# How to properly format FFmpeg's -vf options for both text and snapshots?

Tags: ffmpeg, syntax

I've got this working:

```
ffmpeg -input_format yuyv422 -f v4l2 -s 800x448 -r 30 -i /dev/video0 -vf "[in]drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/Roboto-Regular.ttf:text='%{localtime\:%d %b %Y}':x=8:y=8:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.75,drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/Roboto-Regular.ttf:text='%{localtime\:%T}':x=8:y=24:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.75" -c:v h264_omx -r 30 -b:v 2M -an -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream
```

It outputs a steady video-stream, with a double-lined text overlay, from my USB-connected webcam to rtsp-simple-server on my RPi 3A+.

I've also got this working:

```
ffmpeg -input_format yuyv422 -f v4l2 -s 800x448 -r 30 -i /dev/video0 -c:v h264_omx -r 30 -b:v 2M -vf fps=1/20 -update 1 /dev/shm/snapshot.jpg -an -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream
```

But I can't figure out how to make FFmpeg do both at the same time - a video stream with double-lined text overlay, while saving a snapshot now and then to /dev/shm.

What would the correct syntax for this look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format yuyv422 -video_size 800x448 -framerate 30 -i /dev/video0 -filter_complex "[0]vflip,drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/Roboto-Regular.ttf:text='%{localtime\:%d %b %Y}':x=8:y=8:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.75,drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/Roboto-Regular.ttf:text='%{localtime\:%T}':x=8:y=24:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.75[vid];[0]fps=1/20,vflip[img]" -map "[vid]" -c:v h264_omx -b:v 2M -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream -map "[img]" -update 1 /dev/shm/snapshot.jpg
```

Comment: You wouldn't know how to add the "vflip" option into this commandline? When I try it, the drawtext lines disappear (but the pictures gets flipped). Thanks.